# How to get function inside functions.php file in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I want to get this function from functions.php file

```
function twentyseventeen_excerpt_more( $link ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return $link;
    }

    $link = sprintf( '<p class="link-more"><a href="%1$s" class="more-link">%2$s</a></p>',
        esc_url( get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) ),
        /* translators: %s: Name of current post */
        sprintf( __( 'Continue readingggg<span class="screen-reader-text"> "%s"</span>', 'twentyseventeen' ), get_the_title( get_the_ID() ) )
    );
    return ' &hellip; ' . $link;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'twentyseventeen_excerpt_more' );
```

And in my shorcode file to remove the 'Continue readinggg' text with empty string for example (or simply remove it). How can i do it ?
I have to use into this statement:

```
if($content=='true'){
                                                the_content();
                                            }
                                            if( $excerpt=='true' ) {
                                                if( $readmore=='true' ) {
                                                    echo get_the_excerpt()."<a href='".get_permalink($article_id)."'><button>Read More</button></a>";
                                                } else {
                                                    the_content();
                                                }
                                            }
```

How it can be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the same filter in your shortcode but with a higher priority :

```
your_shortcode_function() {
   // Your code
   add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'my_excerpt_code', 20 );
}
function my_excerpt_code($link) {
   return '';
}
```

The twentyseventeen function has a default priority of 10, if you put a higher priority, it will be executed after, so it should erase the link.

Edited :

Ok, if you just want to remove the excerpt with the_content, you can use this :

```
the_content(null, false);
```

As you can see here :
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/
It should remove the "see more" button.

Comment: I've edited my question. Can you plelase take a look ?

Answer (score 0):

in case someone needs this. Here is my approach:

```php
function get_current_url() {
    $protocol = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https://" : "http://";
    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $fullURL = $protocol . $host . $uri;
    return $fullURL;
}

global $currentURL;
global $currentID;
$currentURL = get_current_url(); 
$currentID = url_to_postid($currentURL);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).